# lodash push alternating into an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
const a1 = [ obj1 ];
const a2 = [ obj1, obj2, ojb3 ];
```

I want to `split` and then `join` this array with an object called "joiner".

I hope for the end result of:

```
const a1Joined = [ obj1 ];
const a2Joined = [ obj1, joiner, obj2, joiner, ojb3 ];
```

I currently have my own function to do this but want to do it the lodash way now. I thought of this but its pretty ugly lodash way below but its also ugly, is there a cleaner way? (ideally, a single lodash method that does this).

```
const a2 = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
const joiner = { id:'join' };
const joined = _.flatten(_.zip(a2, new Array(a2.length-1).fill(joiner)));
joined.pop();
JSON.stringify(joined, null, 4);
```

I noticed the `_.join` function in lodash, but this is just literally the same as `Array.prototype.join`, which was surprising, I was hoping that this `_.join` would do what I was looking for.

Here is my current method:

```
function pushAlternating(aTargetArr, aEntry) {
    // mutates aTargetArr
    let l = aTargetArr.length;
    for (let i=l-1; i>0; i--) {
        aTargetArr.splice(i, 0, aEntry);
    }

    return aTargetArr;
}
```

Comment: `new Array(a2.length-1).fill(joiner)` can be rewritten as `_.times(_.size(a2)-1, joiner)`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe times expects the second parameter to be an iteratee so it would be need to be something like `() => joiner` or `_.constant(joiner)`

Comment: You're right @GruffBunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatMap) to create an array of alternate items and joined and then uses [**dropRight**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#dropRight) to removethe last element.:

```
const joined = _.dropRight(_.flatMap(a2, item => [item, joiner]), 1);
```

or using chaining:

```
const joined = _(a2)
    .flatMap(item => [item, joiner])
    .dropRight(1)
    .value();
```

Alternatively good old pop cold be used to remove that offending last element:

```
let joined = _.flatMap(a2, item => [item, joiner]);

joined.pop();
```

Comment: Not quite... you get an extra `joiner` at the end if you do this.

Comment: Note to posterity: Gruff Bunny has since changed this answer, so my previous comment is no longer true.